# How to create automatic phone call with authentication code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, google-maps

We are to assign a four-digit authentication code to our web users by calling their listed phone number.

It is pretty much like the service of Google Map for business. In their service, if a web user wanted to claim the ownership of a listed store, the user can request a call to the published phone number for that business and obtain the authentication code. With that code correctly entered, Google Map confirms that user account is the owner of that business.

But how did you make it? Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you are asking. Is your question about how you can create the authentication code?

Comment: O, the difficulty is how to send the code to the user via telephone.

Answer (score 1):

[Twilio Cloud Communications – APIs for Voice, VoIP and Text Messaging](http://www.twilio.com/)

How about this service?